# How to show user Full Name in the Page instead of Email ID for FBA Users

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, user

I used below code to fetch user full name but I am getting Email id instead of full name.

Kindly help .

```
public string UserDisplayName
    {

        get
        {
            if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return SplitLogInName(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser?.Name);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Output from above code: `rswain@hotmail.com`

Expected Result: Rajkiran Swain

Comment: Do you want to get the currently logged in user details? If Yes, check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-the-current-logged-in-user-details-in-sharepoint-2013-using-ssom-csom-rest/).

Comment: I used the same code but i am getting email id instead of UserName

Comment: Which code you used from the reference link I provided in above comment?

Comment: SPSite site = new SPSite("http://win-eqalhem27jl:7575/sites/one/");  
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();  
SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;  
Console.Write("SSOM\nUser Information\nUser ID : " + user.ID + "\nUser Login Name : " + user.LoginName + "\nUser Title: " + user.Name);  
Console.ReadLine();